# Spring MongoTemplate upsert entire list

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, upsert

I have a list of objects which I want to insert into a collection. The `mongoTemplate.insert(list);` works fine but now I want to modify it to `upsert();` as my list can contain duplicate objects which are already inserted into a collection. So what I want is insert entire list and on the go check if the item is already present in the collection then skip it else insert it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out `continueOnError` or `ordered` flag like this:

```
db.collection.insert(myArray, {continueOnError: true})
```

OR,

```
db.collection.insert(myArray, {ordered: false})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `unique` index field of your object's `id`(if there is no unique constraint). So that it will make error while you try to insert using same `id`.

Using the unique constraint you insert `array` or using `BulkInsert`

For using `insert` you can set a flag `continueOnError: true` which can continue insertion whenever error found in case of error because of unique constraint while inserting existing `id` of object.

Comment: Ok. So then just follow the flag to insert!

Comment: `mongoTemplate.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED, MyClass.class);
      mongoTemplate.insert(list);` I tried this but not working.

Comment: If I try from mongoclient It shows unique key constraint error

Comment: Try `insert` with `continueOnError: true` flag!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do a bulk-upsert operation is the method `MongoCollection.bulkWrite` (or at least: the only way I know... ;-))

To use it, you have to convert your documents to the appropriate `WriteModel`: for upserts on a per-document basis, this is `UpdateOneModel`.

```
List<Document> toUpdate = ...;
MongoCollection coll = ...;

// Convert Document to UpdateOneModel<Document>
List<UpdateOneModel<Document>> bulkOperationList = toUpdate.stream()
   .map(doc -> new UpdateOneModel<Document>(
       Filters.eq("_id", doc.get("_id")),  // identify by same _id
       doc,
       new UpdateOptions().upsert(true)))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Write to DB
coll.bulkWrite(bulkOperationList);
```

(Disclaimer: I only *typed* this code, I never *ran* it)